# Check when all images are done uploading?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects. In each object there are an array of files..
Im looping through all files and uploading them one by one, which works as expected.. However, i want to show a "success" modal when all files from each object are done uploading..

Im struggling a bit here... The code I have so far:

Im thinking im doing something wrong when I do the check on the:
 if (allFiles.length === filesToQuestions.length) {

```
triggerUploadFiles() {
        let allFiles = [];
        let filesToQuestions = this.filesToQuestions;
        filesToQuestions.forEach((item) => {
            let files = item.images;
            let payload = {
                instanceId: item.instanceId,
                answerId: item.answerId,
                path: item.path,
                fileType: item.fileType,
                optionId: item.optionId
            };

            if (files.length > 0) {
                files.map(async(file) => {
                    let reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

                    reader.onload = async(e) => {
                        // Make a fileInfo object for storing later
                        let fileInfo = {
                            questionId: this.questionId,
                            name: file.name,
                            type: file.type,
                            data: e.target.result,
                            file: file
                        };

                        fileInfo.type.includes('video') ? fileInfo.type = 'video' : fileInfo.type = 'image';

                        if (payload.instanceId && payload.path) {
                            const {response} = await uploadFileToCloudinary(fileInfo.data, payload);

                            try {
                                this.$store.dispatch('surveys/submitFilesToSurvey', {
                                    instanceId: payload.instanceId,
                                    answerId: payload.answerId,
                                    fileName: response.public_id,
                                    type: fileInfo.type,
                                    optionId: payload.optionId
                                }).then((response) => {
                                    console.log('file submitted', response);
                                    allFiles.push(fileInfo);
                                });
                            } catch (e) {
                                console.log('could not upload file');
                            }
                        }

                        // If all files have been proceed
                        if (allFiles.length === filesToQuestions.length) {
                            const delayForCompletedStatus = 2000;
                            deletePendingSurveyByID(this.tempSurveyId);
                            setTimeout(() => {
                                this.isUploadingFiles = false;
                                this.$store.dispatch('modals/toggleModal', 'showModalSurveyCreated');
                            }, delayForCompletedStatus);
                        }
                    };
                });
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Do not mix `await` and `.then()`. Also, do not use `await` for `setTimeout()`.

Comment: I know, changed it to a try/catch... But still, that isn't the problem :)

Comment: May be I was not explicit enough - you are checking `allFiles.length === filesToQuestions.length` at a wrong time. This check must be performed exactly after the `allFiles.push(fileInfo);` statement. You are mixing 2 paradigms here - `await/async` and `Promise.then().catch()` and this leads to mistakes (as yours).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Promise.all()` to check if all asynchronous events are finished.

> The Promise.all() method returns a single Promise that fulfills when all of the promises passed as an iterable have been fulfilled or when the iterable contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of the first promise that rejects.

```
Promise.all(files.map((file) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
     ...
     reader.onload = e => {
        // upload file
        ...
        resolve();
     }
     ...
  });
})
  .then() {
     // all asynchronous events are finished!
  }
```

FYI, I added a simple example of using `Promise.all`.

```js
const promise1 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('first'), 1000);
});
const promise2 = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => resolve('second'), 2000);
});
const promiseList = [promise1, promise2];

Promise.all(promiseList).then(function(values) {
  console.log(values);
});
```